# keep same inodes metadata with rsync or ignore metadata with du

Tags: rsync, disk-usage, inode, file-metadata

I'm trying to synchronize two folders from a remote computer.
I want to use `rsync` to send the folder, and `du` to check if the space used is identical on the remote computer.

The problem is even with a rsync success the metadata is not same for folders. (folder with a lot of files inside)

```
du -sb FOLDER
```

Doesn't give me the same number on the remote computer.

Is there a way to :
- ask rsync to keep the same metadata space
- or ignore metadata size with du
- something else ?